# Running Total for date and sliced category - incorrect dates being returned

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to display a running total by date and category. I should only see dates where there is a category value present. The category can be filtered by report user using a slicer. My tables are:

[image]

[image]

[image: Job:]

[image]

My data model is:

[image]

I want to write a measure to calculate running totals for Forecast.Qty and Actual.Qty, to also take into account a slicer on Job.Job

So if I slice for Job 1, then I need to get:

```
Date      ActualQty1  ForecastQty1
01/01/19  0           25
15/02/19  2.5         25
26/02/19  2.5         33
12/03/19  13.5        33
```

However I am getting all the dates from Dates table being returned, instead of just those with a corresponding value for either Forecast.Qty or Actual.Qty in the underlying tables

My measures are:

```
ActualQty1 =
VAR a =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Dates ), 'Dates'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Dates'[Date] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( a ), 0, a )

ForecastQty1 =
VAR a =
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Forecast'[Qty] ),
        FILTER ( ALL ( Dates ), 'Dates'[Date] <= MAX ( 'Dates'[Date] ) )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( ISBLANK ( a ), 0, a )
```

Example PBIX is here:

[PBIX file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuiIgc_S9J5JhbYoRL4pXaQYHeWHgQ)

Is there any way to return only those dates where the Job selected has a value for either Forecast.Qty or Actual.Qty?

Comment: Are you looking for a running total YTD?

Comment: Yes but in the format as above, so it fills in the 'blanks' on dates where there is no data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're looking for a running total YTD - something like this should work, if I've understood your data model correctly.

```
ActualQty = TOTALYTD ( SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ), 'DatesTable'[Date] )
```

Edit: To correspond with the recent edits made to your question, if you want to return values only for dates which exist in your fact tables, you could wrap the measure in an `IF()`, like so:

```
ActualQty =
IF (
    SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ) + SUM ( 'Forecast'[Qty] ) = BLANK(),
    BLANK(),
    TOTALYTD ( SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ), 'DatesTable'[Date] )
)
```

This checks whether the date has a value for Acual or Forecast, and only returns a value if at least one is present.

Edit (Naz):
Just refined it further to get a 0 on 01/01/19 for ActualQty:

ActualQty3 =

```
IF (
    SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ) + SUM ( 'Forecast'[Qty] )
        = BLANK (),
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        TOTALYTD ( SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ), 'Dates'[Date] ) = BLANK (),
        0,
        TOTALYTD ( SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ), 'Dates'[Date] )
    )
)
```

Edit (Naz):
Just realised it is using a TOTALYTD function, which I dont need as that is not my requirement. So have amended this further using logic from Rory to now give me:

```
ActualQty = 
var a=
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] ),
    FILTER (    ALL(Dates),'Dates'[Date]<=MAX('Dates'[Date]))
    )
RETURN
IF (
    calculate(SUM ( 'Actual'[Qty] )) + calculate(SUM ( 'Forecast'[Qty] ))
        = BLANK (),
    BLANK (),
    IF (
        a = BLANK (),
        0,
        a
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Rory, this doesnt do what I need as it includes EVERY date from the date table, but I only need the dates which have a corresponding Qty value from either Forecast or Actual tables

Comment: I would suggest using a visual filter to exclude unwanted values, in this case. If you really wanted to apply a fix in the measure itself, you could add an `IF` condition to return `BLANK()` for dates where the sum of both Actual and Forecast are blank. Does this make sense?

Comment: I dont need that though, see my example above. Where there is a blank as there is no data on that date, the running total returns the last running total from a date where there was a value

Comment: Just to clarify further, I am looking to return running totals for all dates contained in both Actual and Forecast tables, with no blanks.

Comment: _"dates which have a corresponding Qty value from either Forecast or Actual tables"_ from your first comment contradicts _"dates contained in both Actual and Forecast tables"_ from your second comment. I'm afraid you've lost me!

Comment: Not sure where the contradiction is? If I use your measure, I get running totals for all the dates from the Dates table. I need running totals for all the dates from both the Actuals and Forecasts tables only. As per the example data from question

Comment: Contradiction is between _'Forecast OR Actual'_ and _'Forecast AND Actual'_!

Comment: I have just run my (edited) example measure as a test, and it returns running totals for all the dates from both the Actuals and Forecasts tables only - and doesn't return anything for the rest of the dates in the date table, which I believe is what you're looking for. Hopefully if you try it now you'll get what you need.

Comment: I have just tried amended measure, and there is a blank on 01/01/2019 for ActualQty, but I need a 0 per original post, if this is possible? Cheers